# Return deleted rows in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

It's not efficient to do two queries like `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE clause` and then `DELETE * FROM TABLE WHERE clause`.

So I want to make `DELETE` query and return deleted rows (one query).

I tried to do:

```
DELETE OUTPUT DELETED.*
FROM table
WHERE clause
```

But I have an error:

```
SQLite exception: near "OUTPUT": syntax error
```

How to make it correctly or maybe there is another alternative way to return deleted rows?

Comment: I don't think the `OUTPUT` clause is available in sqlite.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos What is an alternative way to return deleted rows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [DELETE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) has no OUTPUT clause.

After doing the SELECT, all the important data is in the cache, so the DELETE will run quickly.

And because SELECT plus DELETE is the *only* way, it is the *most efficient* way.

---

Since version 3.35, SQLite has the [RETURNING clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html).

Comment: If I add new column  "DELETED" to table. And I will do query `select blah blah` then query `UPDATE selected rows's "DELETED" column to yes`. Would it be more efficient then direct DELETE?

Comment: An UPDATE would require rewriting all those rows; freeing them might be simpler.

Comment: SQLite always rewrites the entire row.

Answer (score 6):

You can return the records deleted with the [returning](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) clause

```sql
delete from myTable returning *
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `changes()` call right after your `DELETE` query: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html

Implementation will vary depending on the language you're using. For example in PHP you could write:

```
$sqlite = new SQLite3('database.sqlite');
$statement = $sqlite->prepare('DELETE FROM mytable WHERE myclause');
$statement->execute();
echo $sqlite->changes();
```